# Forma correcta de definir una función y retornar valores para posteriores cálculos

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

He creado una función que me devuelve una lista de datos actualizada **‘datos_filtro’** (si es que lo requiero) y si no, me devuelve una lista de datos sin actualizar (**‘datos_filtro’**, sin modificar).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datos = [[1,1,'A',3,4,5,6,7,0,0,0,0],
         [1,5,'A',7,8,9,6,5,0,0,0,0],
         [2,5,'A',7,8,9,6,5,0,0,0,0],
         [2,5,'A',7,8,9,6,5,0,0,0,0],
         [1,5,'B',0,3,5,2,1,0,0,0,0],
         [1,5,'B',6,3,5,2,1,0,0,0,0],
         [2,5,'B',0,3,5,2,1,0,0,0,0],
         [2,3,'B',2,2,1,6,3,0,0,0,0]]

criterio = int(input('Ingrese el criterio: '))
numero = 45
asignacion = 9

def parametros(datos, criterio):
    if criterio == 0:
        print('-------Ejecuto la parte del código relacionada a 0-------')
        datos_filtro = []
        for i in range(len(datos)):
            datos_filtro.append([datos[i][0], datos[i][1], datos[i][2], datos[i][3],
                                 datos[i][4], datos[i][5], datos[i][6], datos[i][7]])
        print('\n','Estos datos se mantienen igual')

    elif criterio == 1:
        print('-------Ejecuto la parte del código relacionada a 1-------')
        datos_filtro = []
        for i in range(len(datos)):
            datos_filtro.append([datos[i][0], datos[i][1], datos[i][2], datos[i][3],
                                 datos[i][4], datos[i][5], datos[i][6], datos[i][7]])
        diccionario = {}
        c_list = [1,2]
        for y in c_list:
            diccionario[y] = []

        for i in range(len(datos_filtro)):
            if datos_filtro[i][2] == 'B':
                key = datos_filtro[i][0]
                diccionario[key].extend([5000, 10000])
        diccionario = {key:[np.sum(valor)] for key, valor in diccionario.items()} #--> Finalizo

        for i in range(len(datos_filtro)):
            if datos_filtro[i][2] == 'B' and datos_filtro[i][3] ==0:
                for key, valor in diccionario.items():
                    datos_filtro[i][7] = (diccionario[key][0])
        print('\n','Estos datos se han actualizado!!!')

    datos_actualizados = pd.DataFrame(datos_filtro)
    print(datos_actualizados.to_string(index=False , header=False))

    return datos_filtro, diccionario

datos_filtro, diccionarios = parametros(datos, criterio)

# Otras funciones más abajo que se irán desarrollando, por ejemplo:

def analisis(datos_filtro, numero, asignacion):

    '''Aquí desarrollo más código y eventualmente
    tomaré como parámetros de entrada algunos valores
    retornados en funciones anteriores'''

    pass
```

Pero al hacer esto me he topado con un problema, para esta primera función le ingreso por parámetros 2 cosas: **datos y criterio.**

El criterio funciona siempre y cuando sea 1, ya que si vale 1 me devolverá todo lo que pido en return (**datos_filtro y diccionario**, ya que éste último lo utilizaré como parámetro de entrada en otra función).

El problema es cuando vale 0, ya que ahí lo que pido es que únicamente me devuelva **‘datos_filtro’** sin actualizar, ya que **diccionario** no lo necesito.  El error que me sale es de *UnboundLocalError.*

**COMENTARIO ADICIONAL:**

El caso es que estoy comenzando a estructurar por funciones un código grande que he desarrollado por las siguientes razones:

> 1. No tener ver tantas variables en mi editor de código (en este caso Spyder) que son muchas, sino simplemente las que me interesa
>      visualizar (las que voy llamando).
> 2. Por orden, ya que el código en sí es mucho más grande y funciona, pero como uno solo.
>
>    a.   Al organizarlo en funciones, mi idea es que las cosas que pido
>      devolver en cada función las utilice como parámetros de entrada en
>      otra función más abajo.
>
>    i.   Y a futuro podría pasarle los parámetros que yo quiera.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda y el criterio que me puedan dar al respecto ya que funciones es un tema relativamente nuevo para mí, saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `diccionario` lo defines en el `elif`, si se cae en el `if` cuando se ejecuta `return datos_filtro, diccionario` no existe.

Tienes varias opciones dependiendo del comportamiento que desees:

### Retornar siempre dos** objetos

En éste caso si el criterio es 0 se retorna un diccionario vacío o `None`.

```
def parametros(datos, criterio):
    diccionario = {} # Declara diccionario al inicio
    if criterio == 0:
    # Resto igual
```

Al llamar

```
datos_filtro, diccionarios = parametros(datos, 1)
datos_filtro, diccionarios = parametros(datos, 0)
# Por convención:
datos_filtro, = parametros(datos, 0)
datos_filtro, _ = parametros(datos, 0)
```

### Retornar uno o dos** objetos dependiendo del valor de criterio

```
def parametros(datos, criterio):
    # Resto igual
    return (datos_filtro, diccionario) if criterio == 1 else datos_filtro
```

o:

```
def parametros(datos, criterio):
    if criterio == 0:
        # Resto del código
        return datos_filtro

    elif criterio == 1:
        # Resto del código
        return datos_filtro, diccionario
```

Al llamar

```
datos_filtro = parametros(datos, 0)
datos_filtro, diccionarios = parametros(datos, 1)
```

> ** Realmente no se retornan dos objetos, un método o función solo puede retornar una referencia a un objeto, lo que se hace es
>   empaquetarlos en una tupla y retornar la tupla. `return a, b` es
>   azúcar sintáctica para `return (a, b)`. Por su parte,  `a, b = foo()`
>   lo que hace es desempaquetar la tupla, similar a `res = foo(); a, b = res[0], res[1]`

Comment: Muchas gracias, mi problema ha sido mas bien la lógica de lo que pedía que me devuelva, saludos cordiales.